# MySQL order by priority list

Tags: mysql

I need to order a table but I don't know how columns will be selected by user.

Example:

```
select * 
from table 
order by field1, field2, field3
```

But the user can change fields order: field3, field1, field2

I was thinking in something like that:

```
select * 
from table
order by 
some_fuction (
field1, priority
field2, priority
field3, priority
)
```

Where I can set the priority in each field. Is it possible?

Thanks,
Anderson

Comment: How is the user accessing your data? Via a script? If so, let the script handle it

Answer (score 1):

Using `if`, `case` you can get a solution.
You can look at various solutions posted on SO:

1. [“IF” statement in MYSQL ORDER BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550942/can-you-add-if-statement-in-php-mysql-order-by)
2. [MySQL order by multiple case statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469226/mysql-order-by-multiple-case-statements)
3. [complex sql order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250070/complex-sql-order-by)
4. [MySQL : Conditional ORDER BY to only one column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5422/mysql-conditional-order-by-to-only-one-column)

and may be more ...

Comment: I wouldn't like to use if or case and make something like this:

    select *
    from table
    order by
    case id
      when 1 then field1
      when 2 then field2
    end
    case id
      when 1 then field1
      when 2 then field2
    end
    .
    .
    .

Comment: @user1433588 - These are the only options at MySQL level. Otherwise you have to decide at server script level, before framing the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

if the user is selecting order means... use the parameter to order filed

```
select * from table_name
order by ${filed_name}
```

case makes SQL big